# Looping a triangle from Eloquent JavaScript Variable (Eloquent JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables

This is the solution:

```
for (let line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += "#")
    console.log(line);
```

My question is :   If line = "#", why can't line be used on the right hand side of the `+=` operator like so:

```
for (let line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += line)
    console.log(line);
```

Comment: it ... can ? what is the problem ? this works just fine

Comment: but it multiplies the number of '#' by 2 each time, which is to be expected

Comment: thank you all. But why does it multiply line by 2 each time?

Comment: step 1 : `line = '#'`, `line += line` gives you now `line = '##'`, step 2 :  `line = '##'`, `line += line` gives you `line = '##' + '##' = '####'`... step 3 : `line = '####'`, `line += line` gives you `line = '####' + '####' = line *2 = '########'` ... and so on, you got it ?

Comment: Yes I do!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding line to itself each time, line will grow exponentially. Run the code here to take a look:

```js
for (let line = "#"; line.length < 20; line += line) console.log(line)
```

By doing `for (let line = "#"; line.length < 8; line += "#") console.log(line);`

You ensure that line only increases by one "#" in each iteration.